# How do i can split nginx error.log by date?

Tags: nginx, openresty

I want to split the nginx error.log by date, but not work

here is my code :

```
if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})") {
    set $year $1;
    set $month $2;
    set $day $3;
}
access_log logs/access.log.$year$month$day main;
error_log  logs/error.log.$year$month$day;
```

but the result is :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/562), using variables in `error_log` directive is not allowed.

> It's so by design. Variables are only available with HTTP requests, while error_log is not limited to HTTP.

However you can use logrotate or create a script that do the renaming for you, check the following [related question](https://serverfault.com/q/694965/370663) from ServerFault

Answer (score 0):

Add your block into the server{} block and it should work.

Comment: Adding a specific example would be helpful.